# Criando NavBar para Testar Site Responsivo

Tags: html5, css3, nav-bar

Olá, acho essa pergunta estranha de explicar, mas vou tentar ao máximo para não levar voto negativo haha, vamos la.

Situação: Tenho um site, nele apresento outros templates de sites, gostaria de aplicar uma navbar, com meu logo, alguns botões que voltam para o site e 3 icones, mobile, tablet e desktop, para que mude a resolução da tela e fique fácil de testar versão responsiva.

Caso não entenda, antes de negativar, por favor comente aqui e eu tento explicar melhor.

Resumindo: *estou precisando criar uma navbar fixa no topo da página para visualizar templates de forma responsiva*

Tem um exemplo que poderia mostrar é **ThemeForest**, aquela navbar que utilizam na demo de um theme.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Para quem estava ou está procurando o mesmo que eu, aqui vai a solução:**

*Código mastigado de menu lateral, para testar site responsivo e templates.*

```js
function set_frame_height(){
 var head_h = $('#header').outerHeight();

 //var h = 0;
 var win_h = $(window).height();
 var h = 0;

 // tablet
 if( $('body').hasClass('tablet') ) {
  var h_top = 62;
  var h_max = 781;
 } else if( $('body').hasClass('mobile') ) {
  var h_top = 72;
  var h_max = 504;
 }

 h = win_h - h_top;
 h = h > h_max ? h_max : h; 

 if( !$('body').hasClass('tablet') && !$('body').hasClass('mobile') ) {
  h = win_h;
 }
 
 $('#frame').height( h );
}
function change_template(src){
 var start_x = 50;
 var end_x = 180;
 $('#loading').show().stop(true, true).animate({'left' : end_x}, function(){
  $('#frame').attr('src', src);
 });
 $('#frame').load(function(){
  $('#loading').animate({ 'left' : start_x });
 });
}

$(document).ready(function(){

 var hide_button = $('<span id="hide-button"></span>').appendTo("#customize");
 var loading = $('<div id="loading"><span>Loading...</span></div>').appendTo('#customize');
 var is_mobile_template = $('body').hasClass('mobile');

 set_frame_height();
 $(window).resize(function(){ set_frame_height(); });
 
 $('.colors ol li a').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().find('a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  
  change_template($(this).attr('href'));
  return false;
 });
 $('a.color').click(function(){
  var last_ol = $('.colors > ul > li.active ol');
  $('.colors > ul > li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().find('ol').slideDown();
  last_ol.slideUp();
  $(this).parent().find('ol a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().find('ol a').eq(0).addClass('active');
  change_template($(this).attr('href'));
  return false;
 });
 $('a.color:eq(0)').trigger('click');

 var initial_left = parseInt($('#customize').css('left'));

 $('#hide-button').live('click', function(){
  var container = $('#customize');
  var width = parseInt(container.outerWidth());
  if( !container.hasClass('hidden') ) {
   container.animate( {'left': -1*width+5});
   container.addClass('hidden');
  }else {
   container.removeClass('hidden');
   container.animate( {'left': initial_left });
  }
 });

 // responsive links
 $('.responsive a').live('click', function(){
  $('.responsive a').each(function(){
   $('body').removeClass( $(this).attr('rel') ); 
   $(this).removeClass('active');
  });

  $('body').addClass( $(this).attr('rel') );
  $(this).addClass('active');

  set_frame_height();

  return false;
 });
 $('.responsive a:eq(0)').trigger('click');

 // add note if is mobile
 if( is_mobile_template ) {
  $('body').append('<div class="note">Please use Firefox or Chrome latest version to preview the mobile templates.</div>');
 }

 if( is_mobile() ) {
  $('body').removeClass('mobile');
  $('.note').remove();
  $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no" />');
 }

});

function is_mobile() {
 return navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') != -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Zune') != -1;
}
```

```css
* { padding:0; margin:0; outline:0; }
html { overflow:hidden; }
body { overflow:hidden; font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; background:#fff; font-size:12px; line-height:14px; color:#754a27; }
.cl { font-size:0; line-height:0; height:0; display:block; clear:both; }
a { cursor:pointer;}

#customize { width:200px; position:absolute; top:10px; left:-11px; z-index:10; }

#customize-holder { width:168px; background:#fef9ec; border:solid 1px #d7bb9d; padding:6px 10px 10px 20px; text-align: center; position:relative; z-index:20;}
#customize-holder { -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #999; -moz-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px;}
#customize-holder { -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px #999; -webkit-border-radius:5px; box-shadow:0 0 10px #999}

#frame { position:relative; z-index:1; margin:0 auto;}
h2 { font-size:18px; line-height:18px; }
h3 { font-weight: normal; font-size:13px; border-top:solid 1px #d7bb9d; border-bottom:solid 1px #d7bb9d; padding:8px 0; margin-top:5px; text-transform: capitalize; margin-bottom:1px;}
.colors { border-bottom:solid 1px #d7bb9d; padding-bottom:1px; }
.colors ul{ list-style-type: none; text-align: left; border-top:solid 1px #e9d7be;  }
.colors ul li { }
.colors ul li ol{ padding:5px 0 5px 30px; display:none; border-bottom:solid 1px #e9d7be;}
.colors ul li ol li{ padding:0 0 3px 0; text-transform: capitalize;}
.colors ul li ol li a{ color:#754a27; text-decoration: none; display:block;}
.colors ul li ol li a:hover{ color:#d3b596;}
.colors ul li ol li a.active{ font-weight: bold; color:#333;}
.colors a.color { text-decoration: none; color:#754a27; display:block; height:21px; border-bottom:solid 1px #e9d7be; padding:4px 0 0 6px;  }
.colors a.color:hover { color:#d3b596; }
.colors a.color strong{ float:left; white-space:nowrap; line-height:18px; font-size:13px; padding-left:7px; text-transform: capitalize;}
.colors a.color span{ float:left; width:13px; height:13px; border:solid 1px #e1d4c2; font-size:0; line-height:0; padding:1px; }
.colors a.color span{ -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #c5b099; -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px #c5b099; box-shadow:0 0 5px #c5b099; }
.colors a.color span em{ display:block; width:13px; height:13px; }
.colors a.color span em b{ display:block; width:13px; height:13px; }
.colors a.color span em b{ background:-moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #000); opacity: 0.5; -moz-opacity: 0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50); background:linear-gradient(#fff, #000);}
.colors a.color span em b{ background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(1, #fff), color-stop(0, #000)); }
.colors a.color span,
.colors a.color span em,
.colors a.color span em b{ -moz-border-radius:3px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; border-radius:3px }
.colors a.color:hover span { border-color:#b8926f;}
.colors .active a.color { color:#333; background:-moz-linear-gradient(#fbf4e6, #f1e4cb); background:linear-gradient(#fbf4e6, #f1e4cb); }
.colors a.color:hover,
.colors .active a.color { background:-moz-linear-gradient(#fbf4e6, #f1e4cb); background:linear-gradient(#fbf4e6, #f1e4cb); }
.colors a.color:hover,
.colors .active a.color { background:#f8f0df; background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(1, #fbf4e6), color-stop(0, #f1e4cb)); }
.colors .active a.color span{ -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #492d13; -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px #492d13; box-shadow:0 0 5px #492d13; }
.colors .active a.color span{ border-color:#754a27;}
.colors .active a.color em b{ opacity: 0.1; -moz-opacity: 0.1; filter:alpha(opacity=10); }

#loading { position:absolute; top:21px; left:50px; z-index:3; display:none;}
#loading span{ width:90px; text-align: center; padding:8px 0 8px 22px; background:#fef9ec; border:solid 1px #edddc8; display:block; position:relative;}
#loading span{ -moz-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px;}
.mc-logos { font-size:0; line-height:0; padding:9px 0 0 0;}
.logo { font-size:0; line-height:0;}

#hide-button { width:14px; height:20px; position:absolute; top:50%; right:-14px; cursor:pointer; z-index:20; background:#fef9ec url(images/hide.png) no-repeat 3px center; border:solid 1px #d7bb9d; border-left:0;}

#hide-button { -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px; 
 -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px; border-top-right-radius: 3px; border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;}

.iframe-holder { font-size:0; line-height:0; text-align:center; margin:auto; }

/** mobile body */
body.mobile { background-image:url(images/mobile-bg.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center 10px;}
body.mobile .iframe-holder{ width:336px; padding:72px 0 0 0; }
body.mobile .iframe-holder iframe{ overflow-x:hidden; }

.note { font-size:11px; text-align:center; padding:75px 0 0 0; color:#999;}

/** responsive links **/
.responsive { border-top:solid 1px #d7bb9d; text-align:center; margin-top:10px; font-size:11px; line-height:14px; padding-top:5px; }
.responsive a{ background:#f8f0df; border:solid 1px #d7bb9d; display:inline-block; padding:2px; margin:0 1px;}
.responsive a{ border-radius:3px; -moz-border-radius:3px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; text-decoration:none; color:#754a27;}
.responsive a.active{ font-weight:bold;}

/** tablet body **/
body.tablet { background-image:url(images/tablet-bg.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center 10px;}
body.tablet .iframe-holder{ width:784px; padding:62px 0 0 0;}
body.tablet .iframe-holder iframe{ overflow-x:hidden; }
```

```html
<div id="customize">
 <div id="customize-holder">
  <h2>Responsive Test</h2>
  
    <div class="responsive">
   <a href="#" rel="desktop">Desktop</a>
   <a href="#" rel="tablet">Tablet</a>
   <a href="#" rel="mobile">Mobile</a>
  </div>
    
     <h3>Selecionar Layout:</h3>
    
  <div class="colors">
   <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
      <ul>
    <li>
     <a href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com" class="color" style="color:#">
            <strong>default</strong>
     </a>
     <ol>
            <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
           </ol>
    </li>
   </ul>
      <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  

 </div>
</div>
<div class="iframe-holder">
 <iframe id="frame" src="" width="100%" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Fiquei um pouco na dúvida quanto à sua pergunta, porém usando o Bootstrap você pode fazer o que deseja (interpretei de duas formas possíveis), veja os exemplos a seguir e diga se algum deles ajuda:

1. [Barra de navegação estática no topo](http://getbootstrap.com.br/examples/navbar-static-top/)
2. [Barra de navegação fixada](http://getbootstrap.com.br/examples/navbar-fixed-top/)